# How to write Iterator for a list?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have a class implementing List interface and storing data in an array of Objects. Now I need to write Iterator method for my class. How to get started ? I thought about writing a subclass implementing Iterator interface. Object of the class will have parameters of current index and last index. At each call to next/hasNext those parameters will be modified. Is this approach correct ? But then there is a problem with remove() method, since it should allow to delete object of class calling my iterator. How to solve this ? Also what should happen in iterator() method of my main class ?

My pseudocode:

```
class MyCollection<T> implements List<T>{
    T[] tab;

    MyCollection(int len) {
        tab = (T[])new Object[len];
    }
    public Iterator iterator(){
    }
}

class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator {

    private int current;
    private int last;

    public void remove(){
    }

    public T next(){

    }

    public boolean hasNext(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a class implementing List interface and storing data in an array of Objects.

It looks like you are reimplementing `ArrayList`.  Is there a good reason for doing this?

> Object of the class will have parameters of current index and last index.  At each call to next/hasNext those parameters will be modified. Is this approach correct ?

You should only need one index, I think.  But the basic idea is correct.

> But then there is a problem with remove() method, since it should allow to delete object of class calling my iterator. How to solve this ?

There are two approaches:

1. Remove the element from the array and somehow arrange that the "hole" is filled.  Either a) copy all elements to a new array of size `tab.length - 1`, b) use `System.arraycopy` or equivalent to move the elements after the deleted element, or c) assign null to the slot and change the classes to skip over `null` elements.  (The last is probably a really bad idea ...)
2. Have `MyIterator.remove()` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.  The `remove` method is an optional method according to the `Iterator` API spec.

> Also what should happen in iterator() method of my main class ?

It should create and return an instance of the MyIterator class.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [java.util.ArrayList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29).

Comment: This is the best answer, hands down, for anyone looking to learn how to effectively implement a List Data Structure in Java that takes advantage of Iterators. Thanks Tofu.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyCollection<T> implements List<T>{
    T[] tab;

    MyCollection(int len) {
        tab = (T[])new Object[len];
    }
    public Iterator iterator(){
        return new MyIterator(tab);
    }
}

class MyIterator<T> implements Iterator {

    private int current = 0;
    private int last ;
    private T[] tab;

    public MyIterator(T[] tab){
       this.tab = tab;
    }

    public void remove(){
       throw UnsupportedException();
    }

    public T next(){
        current ++ ;
        return tab[current];
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        current == tab.length - 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not checking if current exceeds array size in next() method

Answer (score 0):

How about extending [java.util.AbstractList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html)? After all that's what all sun List implementations in [`java.util`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) (but not in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)) do.

That way you only need to implement

- [get(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#get%28int%29) and
- [add(E)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#add%28E%29) (if you want to make the list mutable)
- and some Constructors

You get all other methods (including [iterator()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#iterator%28%29)) for free.